# Exposing JSON numbers with Doctrine decimal type using API Platform

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I am creating a web API using API Platform and entities are stored in a SQL database using Doctrine ORM.

Doctrine [maps decimal type to PHP string](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#mapping-matrix). However, I'd like to expose decimal fields as JSON numbers while retaining the `NUMERIC` type in my SQL database. I am well aware that some precision can be lost using JSON numbers but I am OK to ignore it.

I tried using a getter and a setter for the decimal field(s):

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource]
class Product
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'decimal', precision=10, scale=2)]
    private string $price = '0';

    public function getPrice(): float
    {
        return (float) $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(float|string $price): self
    {
        if (is_float($price)) {
            $this->price = number_format($price, 2, '.', '');
        }
        else {
            $this->price = $price;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When serializing the entity to JSON/JSON-LD, the `price` field is correctly serialized to a number using `getPrice()`:

```json
{
  "@id": "/api/products/1",
  "@type": "Product",
  "price": 65.3
}
```

However creating or updating a product with a number for the `price` value throws an error:

```bash
curl -X 'POST' \
  "http://localhost:8000/api/products" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/ld+json' \
  -d '{
  "price": 120.6
}'
```

```
The type of the "price" attribute must be "string", "integer" given.
```

**Edit:** The setter is never called. The error is thrown by `ApiPlatform\Core\Serializer\AbstractItemNormalizer` from [`ValidateType()`](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/e556dce76bf1d0f1cb6b07c73ba2872f1faa182b/src/Serializer/AbstractItemNormalizer.php#L868) which is called by [`CreateAttributeValue()`](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/e556dce76bf1d0f1cb6b07c73ba2872f1faa182b/src/Serializer/AbstractItemNormalizer.php#L749).

**Related:** [Doctrine GitHub issue](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/1647)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown by the normalizer type checker (`ApiPlatform\Core\Serializer\AbstractItemNormalizer` in [`CreateAttributeValue()`](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/e556dce76bf1d0f1cb6b07c73ba2872f1faa182b/src/Serializer/AbstractItemNormalizer.php#L749) that call [`ValidateType()`](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/e556dce76bf1d0f1cb6b07c73ba2872f1faa182b/src/Serializer/AbstractItemNormalizer.php#L868).

This can be circumvented by [adding `ObjectNormalizer::DISABLE_TYPE_ENFORCEMENT` to the normalizer context](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety):

```php
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Context;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource]
class Product
{
    #[Context(['disable_type_enforcement' => true])]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'decimal', precision=10, scale=2)]
    private string $price = '0';

    public function getPrice(): float
    {
        return (float) $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(float|string $price): self
    {
        if (is_float($price)) {
            $this->price = number_format($price, 2, '.', '');
        }
        else {
            $this->price = $price;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the price has no cents?  You may have to check for an integer value as well.  Notice how the 120.60 was truncated to 120.6.  If the price were 120.00 it may come back as 120  And rather test the type, set the price to a float eliminating the need for the `if else`  go with just `this->price= number_format(floatval($price),2)`

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can cast the price as a string like this:

```
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource]
class Product
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'decimal', precision=10, scale=2)]
    private string $price = '0';

    public function getPrice(): float
    {
        return (float) $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(float|string $price): self
    {
        if (is_float($price)) {
            $this->price = (string) number_format($price, 2, '.', ''); //Casting to string
        }
        else {
            $this->price = (string) $price; //Casting to string
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: `number_format()` always returns a string. In the else block, `$price` is necessarily not a float (could be a string or something else). Your solution could only fix an issue if `setPrice()` was called with a `$price` from a type other than float or string.